# CSS remove all generic styling from elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any easy way to remove any styling from my elements, that is applied to "generic" selectors?

By generic I mean, `section` or `p` or `div` or `button` ... basically where it's not targeting the element based on a class or ID but based on the actual element itself.

The problem is I have some HTML and CSS I am outputting on a user's website, but i have no control over their stylesheet that is loaded on the same page.  The problem is when the user's stylesheet or custom CSS targets basic generic HTML elements (like `section` or `button` or `p`).  My code has all specific CSS selectors targeting them, but sometimes sites with this "generic" styling causes display issues with my HTML if I haven't specifically defined a property.

For example, I don't want any specific padding on a `p` element -- so I don't have anything set for `padding` on my `p` elements .. but if the user's stylesheet does -- it is applied to to my element.  I'm trying to not have to define **every single property on every single element of mine**, just to make sure the users stylesheet is not applied to my elements.

Was thinking of something along the lines of this psuedo-code:

```
#my-main-wrapper > section, p, div, button {
    all: unset;
}
```

Where it would unset any styles that are being applied to any elements inside the `#my-main-wrapper` element using basic selectors like `section` or `p` or `div` or `button` .. thus ONLY the styles I have defined that target those elements using specific class or ID are applied.

Comment: Why not use a [CSS reset stylesheet](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/) to remove all browser default styles, and then apply your own styles on top of that?

Comment: Maybe `all: initial`

Answer (score 0):

```
#my-main-wrapper section,p,div,button{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border:0;
}
```

If I understand your problem correctly, this is a simple solution worth trying. Add any more styles you think might be messing up with your stylesheet, but according to me, this should be enough.

As another user mentioned `all: intial` might also be a good solution. But be sure to read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_all.asp) before applying that property as many people end up misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this situation I would go with a generic CSS reset, like:

```
#my-main-wrapper > * {
  all: unset;
}
```

Comment: Surely you want to apply it to all contained elements, not just direct descendants?

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that the selector should apply to direct descendants.

Comment: @DBS, no, fair enough - it is a bit ambiguous. It's not clear if the OP means their pseudo-code selector to be read as: `#my-main-wrapper > section, #my-main-wrapper > p, #my-main-wrapper > div, #my-main-wrapper > button` or as `#my-main-wrapper > section, #my-main-wrapper p, #my-main-wrapper div, #my-main-wrapper button `.